# How to make the workspace toggle indicator disappear in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Every time I switch between workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04, I get this thing on the screen (picture below). Is there any way to completely hide it? I want to be able to switch between workspaces instantly without that indicator lingering for a second on my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called **[Disable Workspace Switcher Popup](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/)**. This extension

> Disables the overlay displayed when switching between workspaces.

Check out this extension at [GitHub](https://github.com/windsorschmidt/disable-workspace-switcher-popup).

---

Another similar extension is **[No Workspace Switcher Popup](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/758/no-workspace-switcher-popup/)**. Note that this one has not been updated for a long time, but it still works with recent GNOME shell versions (3.26/3.28/3.30).

Comment: There really is an extension for everything

Comment: @RocoCTZ Yes, and I personally find GNOME shell hard to use without these extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ to search for GNOME extensions.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to view your installed extensions.

Search for "workspace" at the first URL, above, and install any of the GNOME Workspace extensions, like this one...

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/943/workspace-scroll/

And you'll be able to switch workspaces, without the ugly box, by scrolling whilst pointing the mouse in the top panel.